# Ag-grid predicate function is not executing

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to create a custom filter option using the `predicate` function provided by `ag-grid` :https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#reference-IFilterOptionDef-predicate

```
 {
                field: 'createdBy',
                filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
                filterParams: {
                    filterOptions: [
                        'contains',
                        'notContains',
                        'blank',
                        {
                            displayKey: 'Active',
                            displayName: 'Active Users',
                            predicate: (cellValue) => {
                                console.log('test')    <------ this console never gets printed
                                cellValue == null || /active/gm.test(cellValue.toLowerCase())
                            },
                            numberOfInputs: 0,
                        },
                    ],
                    debounceMs: 200,
                },
            },
```

As you can see above in the code above `test` never gets printed which means the `predicate` function never gets executed

[image: Ui]

But as you can see in the image above `Active` key is present in the Ui but the `predicate` function is not working.

We are using the following version of ag-grid:

```
"@ag-grid-community/angular": "^25.3.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^25.3.0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited - if using ag-grid v25**

```
test: function (filterValue, cellValue) {
  console.log('test');
    return null || /active/gm.test(cellValue.toLowerCase());
},
```

**If using ag-grid v27**

Please can you try your predicate like this?

```
predicate: function (filterValue, cellValue) {
    console.log('test');
    return null || /active/gm.test(cellValue.toLowerCase());
}
```

Does the console.log work then?

Comment: It didn't. I suspect the problem is with the version. I believe the predicate function is not available in version 25.3.0

Comment: @CharanPreet Apologies, I didn't see the version number.  Try calling it "test" instead of "predicate".  It was updated sometime between 25.3.0 and 27.1.0

Comment: It Worked but I suspect this functionality is somewhat different than the `predicate` function for eg: I have mentioned `numberOfInputs:0` still `test` gets printed only after I type something in the input box  what I am looking for is something like this: [ag-grid-doc](https://ns1.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#example-custom-filter-options)

In this example for the athlete column, it has one filter `Starts with A`.
It works without taking any input I want to implement something like that.

So Can you share any old documentation of this functionality?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think numberOfInputs was available in the older versions (I had to add it when I upgraded)

Comment: So for version 25 of `ag-grid` we can use `hideFilterInput: true` instead of `numberOfInputs:0`.
Official Docs:[official_docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.3.0/angular-grid/filter-provided-simple/#example-custom-filter-options)